# PHP Break Apart Array Variables

Tags: php, arrays

I am extracting XML from a feed. There is a tag entitled:

```
<georss:point>34.234 -34.435</georss:point>
```

which contains two variables I am inserting into MySQL
When I run this code, the variable is 'array'. I then place an extract to break out the variables, unsure of next

```
$xmlString = str_replace('georss:point','point',$xmlString);  
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString); 
$items = $xml->xpath('channel/item'); 
$closeItems = array(); 
foreach($items as $item) 
{     
    $latlng = explode(' ',trim($item->point));
    array(
            'lat'=>$latlng[0],
            'lng'=>$latlng[1]
    );

    $lat = array($latlng[0]);
    $lng = array($latlng[1]);

    echo $lat;
    echo $lng;  
}
```

When I place those echo statements (in the last two lines of code), the variables get echod to the screen. However when I place these varaibles outside of the array, the values do not get echod. 
I am attempting to get these variables outside of the array, so that I can insert these variables into the database. I have tried extract on the varaiables, but this prints back to the screen as 'Array'... unsure of what I need to do to extract these variables from the array. Thanks,

Comment: is there only one lat and long, or many?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations.

1) you can [register xpath namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) instead of replacing in the string
2) `array('lat'=>$latlng[0],'lng'=>$latlng[1]);` does nothing. It is a dead store.
3) Instead of

```
$lat = array($latlng[0]);
$lng = array($latlng[1]);
echo $lat;
echo $lng;
```

You can do: `echo $latlng[0].'-'.$latlng[1];`
If you try to `echo` an array, you will always get `Array`.
Use a specific index to echo an individual element.

4) Alternatively you could use [`list`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to store the variables directly
`list($lat, $long) = explode(' ',trim($item->point));`

**Edit**
To insert multiple results into your database, store the results in an array:

```
$lat_long = array();
foreach($items as $item){
    $lat_long[] = explode(' ', $item);
}
```

Then later iterate through this array and do your database insert.

```
foreach($lat_long as $point){   
  //do SQL injection prevention as well
  //INSERT INTO your_table (`lat`, `long`) VALUES ($point[0], $point[1]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Your suggestion makes more sense to me... however when I implement, the values are the same. list($lat, $long) = explode(' ',trim($item->point)); the lat and lng are always the same on all 23 items.

Comment: Ahhh... 'I see' said the blind man! Thank you very much Brian!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your foreach with a version like this...

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($items as $item) 
{     
    $latlng = explode(' ',trim($item->point));
    $new_array[] = array('lat'=>$latlng[0],'lng'=>$latlng[1]); 
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

this should give you a array of your lat/long values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
$lat = array($latlng[0]);
$lng = array($latlng[1]);
```

should be:

```
$lat = $latlng[0];
$lng = $latlng[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Obmitting the array(..) around $latlng[..] would do the trick, I think.

```
$lat = $latlng[0];
$lng = $latlng[1];
```